# Chromebook: Map Search Key to Caps Lock

Tags: 12.04, unity, chromebook

Using crouton, I have ubuntu running on my chromebook. By default, the caps lock key is a search key and opens up the dash home. How can I map this key to be caps lock instead? I am very new to all of this.

Help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I have the same problem. I learned capitalising things using Caps Lock, not the Shift key, so it'd be awesome to be able to use the Search key as Caps Lock on Xubuntu. My typing would be so much faster. Lol. (I'm not sure if you're dual-running, dual-booting, or full-booting, but I used Crouton to set up Xubuntu on my Chromebook. (I run an HP Chromebook 11.))